# QueryException SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, laravel

Why is the following error occurring?

> QueryException SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user
>   'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

My `.env` file is as follows:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:P7auDP3AGgfkYLPbu+2/m7RCLc42Sip/HuXLLQFZiYs=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=student_management
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should clear the cache after changing info in the .env file.

Run the following commands:

```
php artisan cache:clear 
php artisan config:clear 
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 1):

It's either you edit a wrong file or you have not saved the `.env` yet. Because in your error message, it looks like you access the database using user homestead on localhost database, not root on student_management. Make sure you edit the correct `.env`, not `.env.example`. cheers

Comment: of course I already have checked nearly 100 times that I have edited the right file and of course have saved it. But, thanx for trying to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the blank quotes in front of password like this
DB_PASSWORD=""
In the case if you have an empty password.
Hope this solution will work

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning out the system caches...for example for the PhpMyStorm IDE

On the main menu, **choose File | Invalidate Caches/Restart.** The Invalidate Caches message appears informing you that the caches will be invalidated and rebuilt on the next start. Use buttons in the dialog to invalidate caches, restart PhpStorm or both.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these commands to solve the problem

```
php artisan cache:clear 
php artisan config:clear 
php artisan config:cache
```

These commands are use to clear the cache.

Comment: How does this differ from [Vishal Varshney's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44470722/3789665)?

Answer (score 0):

**sudo mysql -u root -p**

1-`CREATE USER '**root**'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '**1234**';`

2-`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO '**root**'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;`